# Subdivide large Android ListPreference

Tags: android, preferences, listpreference

I have a large amount of items (> 200) of which the user can select. I could arrange them into categories. But how could I display this with a ListPreference? There does not seem to be a way to put headers between items or any other way to subdivide the list into smaller parts.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#DefiningPrefs - note `PreferenceCategory` and/or `PreferenceScreen`

Comment: But doesn't this only group different preferences? I have only one preference with a lot of items to choose between.

Comment: sure, youre right, i missed that, make your own custom `DialogPreference` then